# Font Awesome 5 - How to rotate only the mask of an icon?

Tags: mask, css-transforms, font-awesome-5

I have a `fa-info`, with a `fa-comment` as a mask:

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/js/all.js"></script>


<span class="fas fa-info fa-4x" data-fa-mask="fas fa-comment" data-fa-transform="up-1 shrink-9"></span>
```

and it looks like this:
[image]

If I rotate it using css transform, it looks like this: [image]

If I rotate it using `data-fa-transform="flip-h"`, it looks like this: [image]

fun, right? well, no

I need to rotate ONLY the mask (`fa-message`), so the ***i*** stays like the first, and the message icon rotates like the second.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Use `flip-h` and transform at the same time:

```css
body {
  background:pink;
}
.invert {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js"></script>


<span class="fas fa-info fa-4x" data-fa-mask="fas fa-comment" data-fa-transform="up-1 shrink-9"></span>

<span class="fas fa-info fa-4x invert" data-fa-mask="fas fa-comment" data-fa-transform="up-1 shrink-9 flip-h"></span>
```

Comment: great but, why not `rotateY(180deg)`? does it not work sometimes? any disadvantages?

Comment: @Scaramouche it's the same ;) scale is simply shorter :p